# Apache Flink Kafka Itegration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to integrate Apache Kafka 2.11-0.10.0.0 with Apache Flink 1.1.2.  I am using the scala-shell to test it out and I am getting the following error.

Class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint.CheckpointNotifier not found

I have added the org.apache.flink.streaming jar to the class path, but that does not help.  I have imported all the way up to org.apache.flink.streaming.api.checkpoint._.  That still does not help.  Below is the code that I have run in the shell

```
 import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka._
 import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.SimpleStringSchema
 import org.apache.flink._
 import java.util._
 val properties = new Properties()
 properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
 properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
 properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")
 val myFetcher = FlinkKafkaConsumer.FetcherType.NEW_HIGH_LEVEL
 val myHandler = FlinkKafkaConsumer.OffsetStore.FLINK_ZOOKEEPER
 senv.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties, myHandler, myFetcher)).print
```

I have also tried using the FlinkKafkaConsumer081 and FlinkKafkaConsumer082 methods instead of the FlinkKafkaConsumer method and I still get the same error.

I did notice that the flink-connector-kafka jar has not been updated since Feb 16.  Is this the wrong jar to use?  I did find in maven central Flink Connector Kafka Base 2_11.  Should I be using that jar instead?

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a conflict of versions. That class was removed in Flink 1.0, I believe. So you may have a jar from an old version. Check to be sure that everything is updated to Flink 1.1.2

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for the help!